# How to calculate the relative error of a function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

I'm trying to find a function for the relative error $\left(\frac{\Delta k}{k}\right)$ of this function $k=\frac{4\pi ^2m}{T^2}$

I know $\Delta m$ and $\Delta T$

Comment: Differentiate your expression for $k$ to get $\Delta k = . . . . . . $.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the uncertainties of $m$ and $T$ are independent, you can calculate the error $\Delta k$ as 
$$ \Delta k = \sqrt{\left|\frac{\partial k}{\partial m}\right|^2\Delta m^2 + \left|\frac{\partial k}{\partial T}\right|^2\Delta T^2}$$
which in the present case is
$$ \Delta k = \sqrt{\left|\frac{4\pi^2}{T^2}\right|^2\Delta m^2+\left|-\frac{8\pi^2m}{T^3}\right|^2\Delta T^2}$$
and dividing by $k$ gives you the relative error

Comment: Please note that we do not provide answers to homework questions which do not show any effort. At the most, we provide hints. Please refrain from providing complete answers to such questions.